# react-router-native AndroidBackButton is not firing

Tags: android, react-router, react-native, react-router-native

i'm using `react-router-native` with an ejected `CRNA` app. i've added the `<AndroidBackButton>` component to my `<NativeRouter>` as it shows [in the docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/api/AndroidBackButton/children), but it doesn't seem to be firing.

is there some way i can debug this to see if it's just not getting a value properly? i'm using `<Redirect>` and `<Link>` in my app to do the routing, so there should history items for RR to work from.

any thoughts or ideas are welcome.

```
export default props => (
  <NativeRouter>
    <AndroidBackButton>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Flash} />
        <Route path="/will_not_work" render={routeProps => <WillNotWork {...props} {...routeProps} />} />

        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/menu" render={routeProps => <Menu {...props} {...routeProps} />} />
            <Route path="/car_compatibility" render={routeProps => <CarCompatibilityChecker {...props} {...routeProps} />} />
            <Route path="/how_it_works" render={routeProps => <HowItWorks {...props} {...routeProps} />} />
            <Route path="/app_demo" render={routeProps => <AppDemo {...props} {...routeProps} />} />
          </Switch>
        </View>
      </Switch>
    </AndroidBackButton>
  </NativeRouter>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT IT.

after some extensive docs reading and scouring the internet for anyone with an even remotely similar problem, [i found this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3223#issuecomment-145339796).

when i looked at my `MainActivity.java` file, i saw that i had an empty `onBackPressed` function. i removed it, and voilà! my back button works as expected.

here is the removed code from `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 

}
```